# Doctor who audio ordering?

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

Is there a specific order I should attack the audio books/plays for doctor who? There are an awful lot out there so if I'm going to invest money purchasing them is there a specific ordering I should get them in?

Comment: Chronological order, somewhat ironically, seems best.

Comment: @Politank-Z thanks for the input. Why we have a suggested order tag is beyond me then.

Comment: I suppose there are cases where the chronological order is not readily discernible, the obvious choice, or maybe even not best. I don't think this is one of those cases.

Comment: @Politank-Z is it better to listen to them in release order, or release order per doctor?

Comment: I would say release order. There is at least one multi-Doctor story there; if I recall correctly, each Doctor is following the timeline established in their earlier stories. Don't forget to seek out the BBC Radio episodes with The Eighth Doctor, as well.

Comment: @Politank-Z oh, I assumed they're like the novels and generally unlinked or stand alone

Comment: There are some companions unique to audio, timelines set within screen canon.

Comment: There's a good attempt to put all Doctor Who adventures, including audios and novels, in the order the Doctor experienced them on [The Complete Adventures](http://www.eyespider.freeserve.co.uk/drwho/compleat.html) website--just click on any given Doctor to see the list, the audios are the ones in yellow. Something similar is attempted on [this site](http://www.drwhoguide.com/who.htm).